# Problem with Crosscompiling (std, string) for RaspberryPi from Ubuntu

Tags: cross-compilation, ubuntu

I'm using Ubuntu and arm-none-eabi to crosscompile some baremetal programs for the Raspberry Pi, my problem now is, that this:

```
 char ch[32];
    const char doubleout[] = "double received: ";
    std::string doublestring;
    std::string outstring;
    const char string[] = "character received: ";
    double received = 0.0;
    TIME_LOOP(0,periode){
        int32_t retVal = uart->read(ch,32);
        if (retVal > 0){
            write(string,sizeof(string)-1);
            write(ch,retVal);
            write("\n",1);

            doublestring = std::string(ch);
            received = std::stod(doublestring);
            outstring = std::to_string(received);
            write(doubleout,sizeof(string)-1);
            write(outstring.c_str(), outstring.length()-1);

        }
    }
```

Doesn't crosscompile with this error:

```
uart3.cpp: In member function 'virtual void UartTest::run()':
uart3.cpp:48:16: error: 'stod' is not a member of 'std'
 received = std::stod(doublestring);
            ^
uart3.cpp:49:17: error: 'to_string' is not a member of 'std'
 outstring = std::to_string(received);
```

Compiling for Linux (amd64/x86) instead works fine, it also compiles when using C-methods, like atof(), but not with string or stod().

Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by using the compiler option "-std=c++0x".

Comment: Can you maybe give a bit more detail on how you used it?

Comment: Can you explain what those options do and why they help in this particular case?